# Is there a way to have some shared data between different objects?

Tags: php, oop

I'm working on a form class and my current code looks as follows:

```
$Form->addElement(new FormElementText($name, $value));
```

e.g.

```
$Form->addElement(new FormElementText('user_name', $values['user_name']));
$Form->addElement(new FormElementText('user_nick', $values['user_nick']));
```

The string for `$name` will always be the same as the index string for `$values`.

Is there a way to store `$values` in a central place for all form elements, so that I could pass the `$name` argument alone? I suspect no (besides `global $values`), but here's hoping...

**Edit:** Someone was suggesting the use of static properties, but deleted their answer fairly quickly. This seemed to be a workable solution and after trying it out, it does the trick.

```
FormElementText::$values = $values;
$Form->addElement(new FormElementText('user_nick');
```

and inside `FormElementText`

```
$value = self::$values[$this->name];
```

Comment: Create a values object and inject that object

Comment: But take not to create a copy by this...

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate a little more? I don't follow.

Comment: @Steffen Hopefully my new answer might shed a little light and provide a decent answer (and help you avoid bad code via statics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Statics

First and foremost, let's dismiss the need for statics. If you code a static into your object, you introduce an external dependency - coupling your object to the static call, as well as potentially providing global mutable state (a no-no). Don't ever fall for that, and don't listen to those who will try and convince you that "statics are okay in some cases". As a general rule of thumb, they can be easily avoided.

### Solution

> The string for $name will always be the same as the index string for $values.

If they're **always** the same, have a `FormElement` abstract base class handle this for you.

```
/**
 * This is abstract, it cannot be instantiated directly, only inherited from
 *
 * @abstract
 */
abstract class FormElement
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @constructor
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param array  $values
     */
    public function __construct($name, array $values)
    {
        $this->name  = $name;

        /** @todo Check that the index *definitely* exists **/

        $this->value = $values[$name];

       /** @todo Do whatever else you want with other stuff in $values **/
    }
}
```

So you've got your base class that will handle common logic across all your `FormElement` children. Let's use this in your context:

```
/**
 * Inherits the constructor of FormElement
 */
class FormElementText extends FormElement { }

$form->addElement(new FormElementText('user_name', $values));
```

Note you no longer need to specify the key, which is what your initial question was trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the late answer. I wasn't to happy with that static property either and I came up with something somewhat similar. I now add all `Element` objects without a value to my `Form` object (just `$form->addElement(new Element\Text('user_name'))` etc.) and store them in an $elements array inside my `Form` class. I then call $form->setValues($values) which loops over all added $elements and calls `$element->setValue/setSelected/setChecked($values[$element->getName()])`. I probably should've updated my question.